# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloSpring/hello.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, netbeans

I'm new to Spring Framework and trying to build a test project to understand how it works. Based on this tutorial  [Netbeans tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-spring.html), please see my code bellow.

### **CODE:**

### web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>
            /
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>
        *.html
    </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

### dispatcher-servelt.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean class="controller.CarController" 
          p:carService-ref="carService"
    />

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->

    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

### CarService.java

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package service;

/**
 *
 * @author PTOSH
 */
public class CarService {
    public String sayModel(String name) {
        return "Hello" + name + "!";
    }
}
```

### CarController.java

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;
import service.CarService;

/**
 *
 * @author PTOSH
 */
@RequestMapping("/")
public class CarController extends SimpleFormController{
    private CarService carService;    
        public CarController() {
        //Initialize controller properties here or
        //in the Web Application Context

        setCommandClass(Name.class);
        setCommandName("name");
        setSuccessView("helloView");
        setFormView("nameView");
    }

    public void setCarService(CarService carService)
    {
        this.carService = carService;
    }
    public CarService getCarService()
    {
        return this.carService;
    }
    //Use onSubmit instead of doSubmitAction
    //when you need access to the Request, Response, or BindException objects
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command) throws Exception {
        Name name = (Name) command;
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(getSuccessView());
        mv.addObject("helloMessage", carService.sayModel(name.getValue()));
        return mv;
    }
}
```

### applicationContext.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <bean name="carService" class="service.CarService" />
    <!--bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.url}"
          p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}" /-->

    <!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->

</beans>
```

### GlassFish Server log:

> Infos:   Mapped URL path [/car*] onto handler
>   'controller.CarController#0' 
>   Infos:   Mapped URL path [/index.htm]
>   onto handler 'indexController' 
>   Infos:   **FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 637 ms** 
>   Infos:   Loading application [HelloSpring] at [/HelloSpring] 
>   Infos:   HelloSpring was successfully deployed in 3 649 milliseconds. 
>   **Avertissement:   No mapping found for**
>   **HTTP request with URI [/HelloSpring/hello.htm] in DispatcherServlet**
>   **with name 'dispatcher'**

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: How are you accessing `hello.htm` page?

Answer (score 0):

As per the mapping and configuration you should have the jsp files inside the `WEB-INF/jsp` folder.

```
setSuccessView("helloView");
```

In above code `helloView` is converted to `WEB-INF/jsp/helloView.jsp` as per prefix and suffix rule that is defined in `dispatcher-servelt.xml` at `viewResolver`.

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

Make sure you have `helloView.jsp` under `WEB-INF/jsp` folder. Same thing applies for `hello` as well.

As per configuration you have defined controller for `index.htm`. Apply same thing for `hello.htm` if you don't want spring `InternalResourceViewResolver` to come in picture.

```
<prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
```

Comment: helloView.jsp is under WEB-INF/jsp/helloView.jsp

Comment: where is `hello.htm`?

Comment: In the tutorial there is no hello.htm, and the project is running without... [project files: ](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/600x480q90/673/6a5c12.png)

Comment: project structures are looking exactly same it's some where in code. when are you getting this problem?

Comment: Directly, when the navigator is loading the first page

Comment: It means you are accessing it `/index.htm` or `/`? As per welcome file  in `web.xml` it will redirect to `redirect.jsp`. So many jsps that confusing me.

Comment: He is my redirect.jsp :`<%--
Views should be stored under the WEB-INF folder so that
they are not accessible except through controller process.

This JSP is here to provide a redirect to the dispatcher
servlet but should be the only JSP outside of WEB-INF.
--%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% response.sendRedirect("index.htm"); %>`

Comment: why `index.htm` is not directly placed under welcome file list in `web.xml`?

Comment: To show how to redirect a page...? It has no impact on running the project, I tried both...